# SQL How to view 7 days ahead from the current day

Tags: sql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT Booking.StaffID, Booking.BookingStatus, Car.StartDate, Car.ReturnDate, Car.CarMake, Car.CarModel
FROM Booking
INNER JOIN Car
ON Booking.BookingNo=Car.BookingNo
WHERE StartDate - ??
```

I want to be able to view the next 7 days of bookings from `StartDate` automatically from the current day. How do I do this?

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? MySQL? PostgreSQL? SQL Server? Something else?

Comment: perhaps show more information about your table structure?

Comment: where startDate BETWEEN sysdate AND sysdate +7 ... in case you are using oracle

Comment: `where startdate between current_date and current_date + interval '7' day`

Answer (score 2):

To filter queries per dates I prefer to use two filters instead of between. Here you have some examples for different databases (Oracle, MySQL and MSSQL). Notice you must add an extra day in the second filter as is "<". You'll be adding 8, not 7 days. I have also removed time from dates when filtering.

Oracle:

```
SELECT
    Booking.StaffID, 
    Booking.BookingStatus, 
    Car.StartDate, 
    Car.ReturnDate, 
    Car.CarMake, 
    Car.CarModel
FROM 
    Booking
    INNER JOIN Car
    ON Booking.BookingNo = Car.BookingNo
WHERE 
    Car.StartDate >= trunc(sysdate)
    AND Car.StartDate < trunc(sysdate + 8)
;
```

MySQL:

```
SELECT
    Booking.StaffID, 
    Booking.BookingStatus, 
    Car.StartDate, 
    Car.ReturnDate, 
    Car.CarMake, 
    Car.CarModel
FROM 
    Booking
    INNER JOIN Car
    ON Booking.BookingNo = Car.BookingNo
WHERE 
    Car.StartDate >= date(sysdate())
    AND Car.StartDate < date_add(date(sysdate()), INTERVAL 8 day)
;
```

MSSQL:

```
SELECT
    Booking.StaffID, 
    Booking.BookingStatus, 
    Car.StartDate, 
    Car.ReturnDate, 
    Car.CarMake, 
    Car.CarModel
FROM 
    Booking
    INNER JOIN Car
    ON Booking.BookingNo = Car.BookingNo
WHERE 
    Car.StartDate >= DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, getdate()), 0)
    AND Car.StartDate < DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, getdate()), 8)
;
```

Comment: This is a really good answer that covers multiple databases. +1, nice.